# Does a decrease of an entry of symmetric non-negative matrix decrease the norm?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think the assertion would be false but I do not see an easy example. Or is it true obviously?

Suppose we have a symmetric $A=[a_{ij}]$ with all entries non-negative. Now if we decrease a $a_{ij}$ but still keep $a_{ij}\geq 0$ and so is $a_{ji}$, is it necessary the largest absolute value of the eigenvalues of $A$ decrease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectral radius (the largest absolute value of the eigenvalues) of a nonnegative --- there is no need to be symmetric --- $A$ does not increase when one entry decreases but still remains nonnegative.

Proof: By Collatz-Wielandt formula for a nonnegative matrix, the spectral radius
$$r = \max_{\stackrel{x\ge 0}{x\ne 0}}f(x), \qquad f(x) = \min_{\stackrel{1\le i\le n}{x_i\ne 0}}\frac{[Ax]_i}{x_i},$$
$[y]_i$ stands for the $i$'th element of the column matrix $y$. $f(x)$ nondecreases with respect to any element of $A$ and so does the $\max$ operator. Therefore $r$ nondecreases with respect to any element of $A$.

Comment: Thanks， @Hans ，  do I need irreducibility here ?

Comment: @BrianDing: No. By constructing a sequence of strictly decreasing positive matrices approaching a nonnegative matrix, Collatz-Wielandt formula which is valid for a positive matrix can be shown by limiting process valid for a nonnegative matrix.

Answer (score 2):

No, the largest eigenvalue does not have to decrease. Take any diagonal matrix with non-negative entries such that at least two entries on the diagonal are nonzero and not equal. Decreasing the smallest nonzero entry will have no effect on the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: Right, thanks! I should ask whether there is a chance that eigenvalue will increase.

Comment: I do not believe so. Give me a moment to try and formalize an argument.